# How to declare a variable in BigQuery and set it as an argument for EXTERNAL_QUERY?

Tags: sql, select, google-bigquery

I have some external data base connection in my BigQuery project
How can I declare a variable to set it as an argument for EXTERNAL_QUERY
I tried to write this

`DECLARE req STRING DEFAULT 'SELECT * FROM tracker'; SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("tdv3.eu.tracker", req)`

But if I run it like

`SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("tdv3.eu.tracker", '''SELECT * FROM tracker''')`

it works well.
Where I'm wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make it work by using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE as in below example

```
DECLARE req STRING;
SET req = '"SELECT * FROM tracker"';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("tdv3.eu.tracker",' || req || ');'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`:

```
DECLARE INPUT STRING;
DECLARE DSQL STRING;
SET INPUT = "'CSV'";
SET DSQL = 'SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("tdv3.eu.tracker", "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ENGINES WHERE ENGINE=' || INPUT || '")';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE DSQL;
```

Answer (score 0):

BQ does not support passing a script variable to `EXTERNAL_QUERY`.

You must either use a literal string (that is, passing the query string directly to the query), or use a parameter (the error message that you are getting should mention that).

Such a parameterized query would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("tdv3.eu.tracker", @query);
```

Or using a positionnal parameter:

```
SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("tdv3.eu.tracker", ?);
```

Note that [query parameters](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries) are supported in `bq` CLI, API or from your application client, but not by the Console of Classic UI.