# Assign value to a variable in select statement in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to assign value to a variable using select statement in big query

```
SELECT @RowCnt = COUNT(*) FROM Cities
```

This works with sql server but not with bigquery

Comment: Try this.  **DECLARE RowCnt DEFAULT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Cities);**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to declare a variable in BigQuery and set it as an argument for EXTERNAL\_QUERY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63646703/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-bigquery-and-set-it-as-an-argument-for-external-que)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SET and after the equal put the result of the select between parentheses.

```
declare row_count INT64;
set row_count = (select count(*) from Cities);
select row_count;
```